# ImageButton doesn't work on Android Nougat

Tags: android, xamarin, imagebutton, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

Just for background, I'm using Xamarin.

I have this layout axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fondo">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:background="@color/portada">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_36dp_1x"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btn_action1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/ic_check_white_36dp_1x"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/btn_action2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clickable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then on the cs of the Activity I have this:

```
    public ImageButton imgAction1;
    public ImageButton imgAction2;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /* ... */
        imgAction1 = this.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btn_action1);
        imgAction2 = this.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btn_action2);
        imgAction1.Click -= action1_Click;
        imgAction2.Click -= action2_Click;
        imgAction1.Click += action1_Click;
        imgAction2.Click += action2_Click;
        /* ... */
    }
```

But on Android Nougat the click events are never reached. They are only reached if I debug the lines where listeners are added to the imgActions.

Am I doing something wrong? Or what am I missing for my code to work on Nougat?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem with the codes. Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are unsubscribing and resubscribing your Click events it seems a bit unnecessary?